# angularJS can't get scope.data in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I use directive in html, I send ajax with $http in directive'link, then I `console.log(scope.data)`, ther is `undefined` in console of chrome

**this is my code**

```
  todoApp.directive('planProgress', function($http) {
    return {
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $http.get('get_default_data', {
          params: {
            'type': 'day'
          }
        }).then(function(data) {
          scope.data = data.data;
        });
        console.log(scope.data);
        elem.progress();
      }
    };
  });
```

I `console.log(scope.data)` It's `undefined` But, there is `data` attr in scope,
how can I get data in scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http is asynchronous method so ur console would run before then ,so try add inside your then block because then block always run after successful completion of your response

Try this ,you will understand why it is logging correct value

```
todoApp.directive('planProgress', function($http) {
    return {
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $http.get('get_default_data', {
          params: {
            'type': 'day'
          }
        }).then(function(data) {
          scope.data = data.data;
        console.log(scope.data);
        });

        elem.progress();
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Print `console.log` inside `.then`. Since `$http` is `async`. JS won't wait for it to complete and executes the next line, hence you get it as `undefined`

```
.then(function(data) {
          scope.data = data.data;
          console.log(scope.data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

breaking down your link function

```
    $http.get('get_default_data', {
      params: {
        'type': 'day'
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      scope.data = data.data; 
    });

    console.log(scope.data);
    elem.progress();
```

You can see, that the `console.log` is run directly, while the http call is deferred. Therefore, it will log "undefined" and when the call returns `scope.data` will have a value.

If you want to see what is retrieved, put the 'console.log' into the `then`.

But in your template you can just access `{{data}}` and it will be there.